# How to trace individual resources load from GtkMozEmbed?

Tags: python, gtk

I would like to identify the time taken for each resource loaded from a web page using GtkMozEmbed, is there some facility for this ? Both the "progress" and "net-state" signals applies to the entire document, not to individual resources part of the documente.